# In python: unable to convert variable with uint32_t, uint8_t, int16_t value to hexadecimal

Tags: python-3.x, hex, uint32-t

I have a .ini  file with values as below

```
[Value1]
data_type = uint16_t
value = 0x0001U


[Value2]
data_type = uint32_t
value = 0x00000002UL

[Value4]
data_type = uint8_t
value = 5U
```

I am unable to convert these values to hexadecimal as below
Comment: I am easily able to read .ini file using configparser. Let assume i have value as string in variable var and I want to convert that string variable to hex form

```
print (hex(var)) #this should print the  hexadecimal value
```

Comment: How do you read your ini file?

Comment: using config parser ...that is not a issue ...lets assume i have value in variable in string form ....how should i proceed after that ?

Comment: This is an important precision, I couldn't guess what your variable `value` contained. Also, what error does your command raises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
var = '0x00000002UL'
hex(var)
```

Because `hex()` is meant to convert in the opposite direction.  Instead, try this:

```
var = '0x00000002UL'
int(var[:-2], 16)
```

Note you need to skip the `UL` on the end because that's not Python syntax.